# next-sitemap "Error: Expected ';' on Windows 11

Tags: next.js, sitemap

Trying to get a sitemap made for my Next JS site using next-sitemap. From my research, next-sitemap doesn't work on Windows without including cross-env. Any suggestions on what to do?

I currently have my postbuild command set to:

```
"postbuild": "cross-env next-sitemap --config next-sitemap.js""postbuild": "cross-env next-sitemap --config next-sitemap.js"
```

And here is my next-sitemap.js:

```
let policy = {
    userAgent: "*",
};

if (process.env.ENVIRONMENT !== "production") {
    policy.disallow="/";
};

module.exports = {
    siteUrl: process.env.URL,
    generateRobotsTxt: true,
    robotsTxtOptions: {
        policies: [
            policy
        ],
    },
    outDir: "./out"
}
```

[image: SitemapError]

Comment: Have you tried adding a `;` at the end of the `module.exports` declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Tryp running npm run build (or yarn build) first, on this youtube video happened the same to him and he did it like that:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS-6oiwvNnc

I don't think you need the cross-env, but for windows what you have to do is changing the file name instead. [See the docs here](https://github.com/iamvishnusankar/next-sitemap#building-sitemaps).

Answer (score 1):

For me worked, set the next-sitemap files with the prefix config on the final name (next-sitemap-config.js) and in package.json on script `next-sitemap --config next-sitemap-config.js`.